# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '1' is not a valid attribute name in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem in my code, it is functional and but it bugs me with the console error I am getting from chrome.

My blade template code is:

```
<select name="business_unit_id" class="form-control">
 @foreach (App\Models\BusinessUnit::all() as $data)
  <option value="{{ $data->id }}"
   {{ old('business_unit_id', $cost_centers->business_unit_id ?? null)
    != $data->id ?: 'selected' }}>
    {{ $data->code.' - '.$data->descr }}
  </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

The console error are:

```
app.js:41637 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '1' is not a valid attribute name.
    at baseSetAttr (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43932:8)
    at setAttr (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43907:5)
    at Array.updateAttrs (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43862:7)
    at invokeCreateHooks (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43218:22)
    at createElm (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43105:11)
    at createChildren (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43202:9)
    at createElm (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43103:9)
    at createChildren (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43202:9)
    at createElm (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43103:9)
    at createChildren (http://ksakuws1137/js/app.js:43202:9)
```

The culprit is below, but that is needed to in order for the program to behave correctly.

```
{{ old('business_unit_id', $cost_centers->business_unit_id ?? null)
    != $data->id ?: 'selected' }}>
```

Anyone encounter the same issue and have a resolution? Thanks.

Comment: The error is related to javascript, not what you posted. Do you have a Vue component in your template?

Comment: I do not use Vue. I even tried to try the command npm run serve and composer dump-autoload to no avail.

Comment: The culprit is causing malformed HTML to be rendered. Try to render just the culprit in `<p>` tags and see if you get the same error. Also advise using `!==` instead of of `!=` for comparisons. JS does some weird ass type comparisons.

Comment: changing != to !== didn't solve the problem. Can you write how I can render in <p> tags based on my code provided for me to try?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by changing the code in blade template from:

```
{{ old('business_unit_id', $cost_centers->business_unit_id ?? null)
    != $data->id ?: 'selected' }}>
```

To:

```
{{ old('business_unit_id', $cost_centers->business_unit_id ?? null)
                                != $data->id ? '' : 'selected' }}
```

The culprit then is the "?:", maybe not compliant with HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue. Hope this will help others looking for an answer. for me it was the inline blade `@if` statement. I am not sure but, think Vue is trying to interpret it as some js method.

I had this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="as_template" @if($page->as_template) ? checked @endif>
```

had to change it to

```
@if($page->as_template)
    <input type="checkbox" name="as_template" checked>
@else
    <input type="checkbox" name="as_template">
@endif
```

Comment: I think your problem is the question mark, try to remove it and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: It’s an answer 